# How to wrap command execution in a function to allow either execution or printing of the command; issue with redirection

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I wrote some BASH code that executes a lot of external commands (causing side effects).
So for developing and debugging I thought I wrap the executions in a shell function, so that the commands will either be executed or printed.

So that basic code is:

```bash
run()
{
    if [ "$print_commands" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "$@"
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}
```

Unfortunately most of the external commands output something when successful (like "success"), so I had been using `> /dev/null` to redirect such output.
However there are some status queries that *do* output the status, and that cannot be discarded.

So obviously I *cannot* add `> /dev/null` inside `run`; also I don't want to add a second function that redirects, duplicating most code.

I tried a solution like this:

```bash
silence='>/dev/null'
run some_command with params $silence
```

The idea was to set `silence` to the empty string when just printing the commands, which works, but when executing the commands I get:

> error: unrecognized arguments: >/dev/null

Is there some half-way elegant solution without using `eval`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not check another variable in the `run` function use it to determine redirection?

```
run()
{
    if [ "$print_commands" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "$@"
    elif [ "$silence" -ne 0 ]; then
        "$@" > /dev/null
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}
```

Then:

```
silence=1 run some_command with params whose output is not needed
silence=0 run some_command with params whose output is needed
```

Or you could output the command to stderr instead of stdout:

```
run()
{
    if [ "$print_commands" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "$@" >&2
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that the syntax "var=val cmd ..." can be used for shell functions, too; I thought it's only available for external commands. Redirecting to `stderr` is not an option as there could be real error messages and I intend to paste the output to a terminal for execution (or into another script). See also the related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/726124/320598

Comment: @U.Windl the more I look at this, the more it feels like you're reinventing `set -n`

Comment: You should be a bit more verbose on `set -n` (how to use it here?).

Comment: @U.Windl to me it looks you have some script or something in which you prefix the commands with this `run` function. Instead of that, run the script with `bash -n`, or run `set -n` conditionally at the top of the script.

Comment: Sorry, but when using `bash -n my_script`, then *nothing* is being executed, so nothing is being output. I don't see the usefulness of `set -n` still...

Comment: @U.Windl ah, sorry, it should be both `-n` and `-v`, so `bash -nv`.

Comment: Still that does not help: It outputs the lines of my script, but not what the script would execute. Maybe my description of the problem was not good.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726123/320598 I decided to add an additional first parameter to `run` to control redirection to `/dev/null`:

```bash
run()
{
    declare silence="$1"; shift
    if [ "$print_commands" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "$@"
    elif [ "$silence" -ne 0 ]; then
        "$@" > /dev/null
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}

run 0 non_redirected_command params
run 1 redirected_command params
```